# How to process a file's characters one by one efficiently

Tags: bash, performance, sed, char, iteration

Is there a way to iterate through a file character by character and selectively replace characters based on certain conditions?

I have found a way using a `while` loop and the `sed` utility:

```
while IFS= read -r -N 1 old; do
     ...
     sed -i 's/'$old'/'$new'/g' "$1"
done < "$1"
```

I think this way approach is very slow for large files.

Is there a way that I can achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: Please add example input and the required output, maybe you want the give more details about "certain conditions".  
The canonical tools to replace  characters are `sed` or `tr`.

Comment: This example doesn't work as listed.  You appear to editing in place with `sed` at the same time you are reading from the file.

Comment: Yes, calling `sed` on every single character would be slow.  Consider writing a single `awk` script that handles all the I/O in one process.

Comment: `sed` also supports multiple operations per file/line. Just chain them together with `;` chars, i.e. `s/a/A/g;s/b/B/g;...s@/@FwdSlash@';s/z/Z/g' file` Else, please update your Q with small set of sample data, required output and your best attempt to solve the problem, as well as current output and error msgs. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found what i was looking for! I wrote the following code with one while loop-reading lines and one for loop-reading each character in the specific line. This way is faster and new line remains untouched too! I would be glad if this answer helped other guys too!

```
#!/bin/bash
lineCounter=1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    output=''
    for (( i=0; i<${#line}; i++ )); do

        oldChar=$( printf "${line:$i:1}" )

        ...Compute newChar...

        output+=$newChar

    done
    line2=""
    line2+=$lineCounter
    line2+="s"
    sed -i "$line2/.*/$output/" "$1"
    lineCounter=$((($lineCounter) +1))
done < "$1"
```

Comment: By removing the pipe and adding `[[ -z "$line" ]] && continue` just before `output=''` should become even faster. Operator `-z` returns true if line is empty , `continue` goes to next line of file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot faster to load the whole file at once, generate the desired output and then write it all out at once.

You can do something like:

```
input=$(<"$1")
output=''
for ((i=0; i<${#input}; i++)); do
    old=${input:i:1}
    ...
    output+=$new
done

printf '%s' "$output" > "$1"
```

Comment: This works perfectly with one line file. However, i think if the file has 2 or more lines, in the new file there will be only one line, correct?

Comment: Well `input=$(<file.txt)` will read in all of `file.txt`, including the newlines.  The only thing is you have to be careful when you process the characters that you don't do something like `new=$(echo "$old" ... )` because the `$()` construct removes trailing newlines, so if `$old == $'\n'` you'll get back `''`.

Comment: While this definitely speeds things up _compared to the OP's approach_, it is _still slow overall_, because looping in _Bash_ code is _inherently_ slow. Also, as you state, your approach
requires reading the entire file  into memory _as a whole_, which can be problematic with large input files.

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 performance killers** in your approach:

- Using a *shell loop* to process data.
- *Calling an external utility* (`sed`) *in every iteration* of that loop.

  - Specifically, there's no reason to rewrite the file in *every iteration* of your loop.
  - Also, as has been pointed out, you're *replacing the file you're reading from* in every iteration, which won't work.

**Alternatives**:

- As has been suggested, `sed` may be all you need it, because it supports chaining multiple `s///` calls (with `;`) as well as using characters *sets* and *ranges* in a given call.
- `tr` is an efficient utility that also supports sets and ranges, but it is limited to 1-to-1 character mapping (you cannot map a given character to *multiple* output characters).

If you really need to **process *character by character***, **use a text-processing *utility* rather than shell code**; e.g., with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'\0' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { printf "[%s]", $i }; print "" }' <<<$'abc\ncde'
[a][b][c]
[c][d][e]
```

- `-F '\0'` tells Awk to break each line into individual characters, with `$1` representing the 1st char, ..., and `NF` reflecting the count of characters on the line.
- The example command simply encloses each char. in `[...]` to demonstrate that the per-character processing works; `print ""` at the end simply emits a trailing `\n`.
- To combine this with in-place updating (loosely speaking), use:
  `awk -F'\0' '{ ... }' "$1" > "$1.$$" && mv "$1.$$" "$1"`

  - With *GNU* Awk v4.1+, you can also use `-i inplace` to get the same behavior as with `sed -i`.